# Why do I have 2 identical documents that are both Parents

Tags: xpages

I am developing a method to allow the service owner to deal with conflicting and duplicate Notes documents in an XPages application.  I have created a resolution for the service owner to deal with any duplicates and conflicts that occur but just found that I have a few Notes documents (they are Contracts) that are duplicates because they have the same Contract ID but they are BOTH PARENTS and not one parent and one response, so they are NOT picked up by the view formula SELECT @IsAvailable($Conflict)

Why is this?  How can I create a view to find these?

Answer (score 2):

If a Replication/Save document is edited, it is promoted to a main document. One option may be an agent running overnight to move such documents into a Folder or code in your save function to abort if it's not a main document.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks.  I see.  I am not that expeienced in Notes etc.  I had written an agent to find these and delete one and this worked but trouble is I could do with creating a view for the data owner to be able to view the two and THEY decide which one to delete.  Can I create a view to list these?  I tried the following but it doesn't work.  SELECT @If(@Count(@GetField(conContractid) > 1))